# How to run a shscript on reboot

Tags: ssh, cron, ubuntu-16.04, sh, reboot

I am trying to run a script on reboot that enables a port forward to a remote server. I made i script that it works if i run it in terminal. But i am not able to run it on crontab reboot:

```
@reboot sleep 120000 && sh /home/user/doit.sh
```

where i can see a errlog for the crontab? I have another script in crontab it reboot command and it works. This one no. This script calls SSH to make a tunnel.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add some information on your OS. Without it it is just guesswork. `sleep`'s argument is in seconds, so you specified a one day and a half gap between reboot and the call to your script. On the other hand, there are better ways to run a command when the network goes up. What to use may depend on the Linux distribution.

Comment: i thought the sleep was in miliseconds. Changed it... My OS is Ubuntu Server 16.04

Comment: Fixed it!. There was one charater wrong and the sleep was in miliseconds. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have **systemd**-based system, you might consider adding a `.service` file, e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/ssh-tunnel.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH tunnel
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/user/doit.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You might change the unit type to `Type=simple` if your script does not fork. Afterwards you just have to reload **systemd**, enable the unit and try starting it:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable ssh-tunnel.service
systemctl start ssh-tunnel.service
```

If everything works fine, the tunnel will be established as soon as networking is ready.

Comment: does not work:  Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/user/doit.sh: Exec format error. I have done chmod +x /home/user/doit.sh

Comment: besides the chmod +x i need to add a shebag at the script:#!/bin/bash and this worked. Thank you